# Phone dying at 23% charge

Tags: battery, charging, oneplus-one

I changed the battery of my OnePlus one (original and new, from EBay).
Everything went well, the new battery seems to do its job.
But now my phone keeps turning off and vibrating at 23% charge....
If i connect it to a charger, the "battery-to-empty-to-turn-on" screen shows (as usual) and the phone boots with 23% charge displayed.
Could it be faulty calibration data because i didn't charge the new battery till 100% yet?

Comment: What happens if you charge it to 100%?

Comment: I charged it many times to 100% now, it doesn't change anything. It's always vibrating while the screen turns off. No Shutdown-Message from Android though.